# Best way to install brightway on server allowing multiple users, centralized storage of databases, shareability

Tags: brightway

In my institution we are trying to transition to bw2 .

Obviously everyone might have his local installation but we would like to have a more centralized approach by storing the group's db on the server and be able to track all changes made e.g. using VCS (e.g. every concluded work would be a bw2 project pulled to the database on the server where the commit would contain a description of what this project contains).
Basically the goal would be to obtain something in between simapro multi-user and the [openlca collaboration server](https://www.openlca.org/collaboration-server/) .

The initial idea was to have bw2 (and activity browser) installed locally in each one's local machine pointing to the BRIGHTWAY2_DIR on the server. This might work but would certainly not be ideal since it is not interesting to put in a version control system binary files.

Might [store each dataset as a JSON file](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/technical/bw2data.html#json-database) solve the problem?
If so, any idea on how to implement this or any other suggestion on how to achieve our goal and what could be other issues to deal with?